# How to use "disableAlpha" with EditText / How to change attribute in AttributeSet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I want my Edittext to grey-out less or more than standard when disabled with editTxtV.setEnabled(false).
Oviously the disableAlpha-Property does exactly this.
But using android:disabledAlpha="2.0" like this in layout.xml

```
<EditText android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/EditTextV" android:text="1" android:disabledAlpha="2.0" ></EditText>
```

do not change the behaviour at all.

Hot do I correctly change "how much to grey out"?

Sebastian

PS: 
One idea is to make a custom View extending EditText. In the constructor I get attrs AttributeSet and give that back to super.constructor, but how to change the disableAlpha-attribute on its way through my constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Alpha values should range from 0.0 to 1.0, any values greater than 1.0 is considered as 1.0.